# Send (me) an email when an answer is posted

Tags: support

I recall when I asked my first question that there was a checkbox (that I checked) instructing StackExchange to send me an email when an answer (comment as well?) was posted.

Answers were posted but I received no emails. Did I do something wrong?

When I posted subsequent questions I could not find that email option.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You should see this on the [Ask Question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) page:

[image: screenshot]

If you click `(settings)` it will show you frequency options, for a maximum frequency of every 3 hours.

It's possible that the email wasn't sent because you had viewed the post in the intervening time — I'm not sure if it works similar to the inbox (which I believe by default will email your notifications for answers, comments, etc. *only when you haven't viewed them* in about 48 hours).